# Firebase Messaging: Use two Firebase Projects in one App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I will be distributing an android library that uses FCM to push notifications to any app using my library. The library uses its own Firebase Project google-services.json. The problem is what happens when an App, using my library, already uses FCM with its own google-services.json.

Can the App support both FCM in the main App, using its google-service.json, as well as the library, using its own google-service.json?

To test this I created a sample App using my library. First thing I noticed is there is only one FCMToken. So I assume the same FCMToken would need to be used from both App Firebase Project and Library Firebase project.

I tested, using Firebase console, I sent a message from both projects. I sent a sample message targeted at the FCMToken. The app successfully received a message from the Library Firebase project but did not work for the App Firebase project.

If my scenario, with FCM in both App and Libary, possible? If so, how?

Comment: I won't expect it to work as this will allow apps to use multiple free small firebase databases and avoid using a non-free bigger one.But why do you want to use your FCM where you can use the user one?

Comment: You make a good point. However, since FCM does not cost I figured it would make using my Library easier.